# Adding value to every element in dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, r, numpy, dataframe

I'm new to python (/programming) and have a fairly rudimentary question:

I want to take a data structure (basically a data frame but unsure if that's the most efficient structure) that's got numerical values as follows:

```
     0     1     2     3     4     5
 0  0.0   1.0   7.0  22.0  14.0  28.0
 1  0.0  99.0  15.0  99.0  99.0  99.0
 2  1.0   0.0  21.0  18.0  21.0  14.0
 3  2.0   6.0  20.0  38.0   8.0  21.0
 4  2.0   6.0  20.0  39.0   8.0  16.0
 5  2.0   9.0  99.0  39.0   8.0  16.0
 6  2.0   9.0  99.0  39.0   8.0  21.0
 7  2.0   9.0  99.0  99.0   8.0  16.0
```

I want to add a value (e.g. 1) to each cell at a time, while keeping the others constant i.e. change the first row to

```
1.0   1.0   7.0  22.0  14.0  28.0
0.0   2.0   7.0  22.0  14.0  28.0
0.0   1.0   8.0  22.0  14.0  28.0
0.0   1.0   7.0  23.0  14.0  28.0
0.0   1.0   7.0  22.0  15.0  28.0
0.0   1.0   7.0  22.0  14.0  29.0
```

I want to do that for each row in turn, and probably save the collection of modifications to a list.

As mentioned, I'm fairly new at this and I only managed to change the elements all at once, or I can change them sequentially, but then the previous modifications remain in place.

```
options=[]
import numpy as np
f = np.array(Data)
for i in xrange(8):
    for j in xrange(6):
    f[i,j] +=1
    options.append(f)
```

Any solutions in python or R welcome!

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you write "_Any solutions in python or R welcome!_", it makes your question very broad. Although I could happily provide a possible R solution, I think you should try to focus on a _specific_ programming question in one programming language per question. In your case, python seems like the main priority. You may have a look at a meta post where this is  discussed: [Do I make separate questions for separate programming languages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272888/do-i-make-separate-questions-for-separate-programming-languages). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced with numpy, but you should be able to do with the following;

```
class matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, size, values):
        self.width = size[0]
        self.heigth = size[1]
        self.size = size
        if len(values) != self.heigth*self.width:
            raise ValueError("values don't match dimensions")
        else:
            self.data = []
            for y in range(len(values)):
                if y%self.width == 0:
                    self.data.append([])
                self.data[y//self.width].append(values[y])
    def addfloat(self, value):
        output = self.data
        for y in output:
            for x in y:
                output.append(x + value)
        return matrix(self.size, output)
```

basicly I create a "matrix" class, then write a function for it that does the float adding.
Example;

```
matrix((2, 2), (1, 2, 2, 1)).addfloat(1.2).data
```

returns

```
[[2.2, 3.2], [3.2, 2.2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid retaining your earlier modifications, you could create a copy of the array before modifying it or appending to the list, something like:

```
import numpy as np

options = []
f = np.array(Data)
for i in xrange(8):
    for j in xrange(6):
        ar2 = f.copy()
        ar2[i, j] += 1
        options.append(ar2)
```

It can be even better to avoid explicit looping over the array at all, however. For your numpy array `f`, this could look like:

```
options = (np.identity(f.size)+f.flatten()).reshape((f.size,)+f.shape)
```

Which would return a 3-dimensional numpy array, from which you could extract your desired 2-d numpy arrays with indexing similar to what you'd use for your current list.

As an aside, is `Data` a pandas dataframe, as it appears to be in your first code block? If so, you can get a numpy array from it with the `values` attribute, `Data.values`, and do not need to not need to explicitly create an array out of it.